# Single Sign-On for SAPUI5 app: how to set up?

Tags: single-sign-on, sapui5, sap-basis

I have a SAP sso2 service enabled in the company, how would I enable single sign-on in code? What do I need to insert to my code and possibly where?

When I log in to portal, single sign-on feature works, as I am not asked for password every time. I would like to have the same thing for my SAPUI5 application.

Can I possibly use cookies? If yes, how?

Comment: How does your application authentication work and where will your application be hosted (in the SAP Portal, in an ABAP AS)? How and where are you fetching backend data from (SAP system or non SAP system)?

Comment: the appis hosted on hana system, and data is also fetched from hana db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have the same thing for your SAPUI5 application. You don't need to code anything. SSO for ABAP is standard configuration. You can use any of these:

- SPNego for ABAP (included in SAP Single Sign-On 2.0)
- SAML to Active Directory (assuming your users are there and that's why you have SSO to Portal)

When your company has implemented SSO for Portal, they should of course do the same for SAP GUI and ABAP HTTP. :-)

Note that there is a licensing cost for SAP Single Sign-On 2.0.

Comment: thank you for that, but have you any tutorials for them? stuff I found on SAP site is not very clear on how to implement it. Btw, does that mean that everyone has to install SAP Single Sign-On 2.0 or how exactly does that work?

Comment: No installation at clients for either of them. Here's a guide for SAML: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-42915

Comment: Useful, but still not what I am looking for exactly. I need step by step guide how to do that, the link you have sent me is just describing steps taken for that particular example. I need something more.. universal? Like places where I would need to insert the code etc.. as I said am very new to this so either if you could elaborate or maybe know the guide which is step by step that would be great. By the way I saw that presentation you linked already.

Comment: There is no coding involved. You need to make some configuration changes on ADFS (add a relay party) and activate SAML in your SAP system. Transaction SAML2 will guide you through it for AS ABAP. If you are running Hana XS: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2015/03/14/use-saml-to-enable-sso-for-your-xs-app-on-sap-hana-sps-09-rev-92-or-later

Answer (score 0):

If you use ABAP on-premise system for your SAPUI5 app, then you need to have [SAP Single-Sign-On solution](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_SINGLE_SIGN-ON/3.0/en-US) installed, it includes [SAML support](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Security/Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0#SingleSign-OnwithSAML2.0-SAML2.0inASJava).

SAML implementation on AS ABAP is provided by CommonCryptoLib (SAPCRYPTOLIB) so what you need here:

1. Install [SAPCRYPTOLIB library](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1848999) server-side.

   Not needed on Netweaver 72x/74x kernel PL released after November 2013, because now built-in kernel.
2. [Enable](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f118a8960caf41808bd374e28a834f58/7.52.0/en-US/4ab4c93185376d61e10000000a42189c.html) SAML provider in AS ABAP in SAML2 transaction
3. [Configure](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f118a8960caf41808bd374e28a834f58/7.52.0/en-US/4ab6df333fec6d83e10000000a42189c.html) AS ABAP as service provider
4. Set up SAP SSO

After that you will be able to connect to ABAP system from your app.

If you connect to SCP cloud ABAP or HANA system, then this is even more simply because it supports SAML natively.